# Add dots to fadein slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'dont know javascript enough to add dots navigation to this script, but I really need to use this script.

Can someone add a dot navigation to this script ?

```
(function() {
    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;
    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(600)
            .delay(4000)
            .fadeOut(600, showNextQuote);
    }
    showNextQuote();
})();
```

Comment: explain well what you trying to do .. 1- what that script do .. 2- what you need from that code to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give `position: relative;` to your slider container and your dots container `position: absolute;` so you place the dots wherever you want.

I some dots, equal to length of `.quotes`. They're just spans with actual dot and has `class="dot"`, the normal dot has a black color and the active one white. You can use images instead while the active one has a different `src`. `.active` added to the corresponding dot and removed from the previous.

```
var quotes = $(".quotes");
var quoteIndex = -1;

for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++)
    $('#dots').append($('<span/>').addClass('dot').text("."));

function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    $('.dot.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.dot').eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length).addClass('active');
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(600)
        .delay(4000)
        .fadeOut(600, showNextQuote);
}
showNextQuote();
```

Added a little CSS transition to make the transition smooth.

```
.dot {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 10px;
    transition: color 600ms ease-in-out;
}
.dot.active {
    color: white;
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/x2xf1g8k/)

**EDIT:**

To make the dots clickable, give them `cursor: pointer;` so they look clickable and then give them click listeners:

```
$('.dot').on('click', function() {
    $('.dot.active').removeClass('active');
    clicked = true;
    $(this).addClass('active');
    quoteIndex = $(this).index()-1;
    $('.quotes').hide();
    $('.quotes').eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

[**Updated jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/x2xf1g8k/1/)

Comment: Is there a simple way to make dots clickable ? You know to navigate.

Comment: I might abuse but, i'm not abble to make a pause/stop on mouse over and then restart on mouse leave.  Can you help ?